# Loop a function (including input) until a specific input is pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on some homework and have been tasked with creating a simple program that:

- Gets user input
- Check that said input is in the correct form (two words with ',' separating)
- Outputs the input as two separate words
- And loops all of the above until 'q' is input

It has to come out exactly like asked, and I have it doing so at the moment. I just can't figure out how to loop the prompt back and get different input without it being an infinite loop or never actually taking the new input.

Here is what the output should look like once done:

```
Enter input string:
Jill, Allen
First word: Jill
Second word: Allen

Enter input string:
Golden , Monkey
First word: Golden
Second word: Monkey

Enter input string:
Washington,DC
First word: Washington
Second word: DC

Enter input string:
q
```

I can get it through the first entry and make it quit with 'q,' but can't get it to prompt the user again and get a different input.

Here is my code:

```
def strSplit(usrStr):
    while "," not in usrStr:
        print("Error: No comma in string.\n")
        usrStr = input("Enter input string:\n")
    else:
        strLst = usrStr.split(",")
        print("First word: %s" % strLst[0].strip())
        print("Second word: %s\n" % strLst[1].strip())


usrStr = input("Enter input string:\n")

while usrStr != 'q':
    strSplit(usrStr)
    break
```

Any help would be fantastic! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
while True:
    usrStr = input("Enter input string:\n")
    if usrStr == 'q':
        break

    if "," not in usrStr:
        print("Error: No comma in string.\n")
    else:
        strLst = usrStr.split(",")
        print("First word: %s" % strLst[0].strip())
        print("Second word: %s\n" % strLst[1].strip())
```

Of course, you could still use your `strSplit` function with some modifications:

```
def strSplit(usrStr):
    if "," not in usrStr:
        print("Error: No comma in string.\n")
    else:
        strLst = usrStr.split(",")
        print("First word: %s" % strLst[0].strip())
        print("Second word: %s\n" % strLst[1].strip())

while True:
    usrStr = input("Enter input string:\n")
    if usrStr == 'q':
        break

    strSplit(usrStr)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out over this haha. So when you did the first while loop, is that basically just asking the user to input something every tick (not sure if that's the right term), and then breaking that loop when q is hit?

Comment: @CameronMcMains The correct term would be "every loop" or "every iteration", not "every tick". :)

Comment: @CameronMcMains Yeah, that's essentially the gist of it. The important thing to remember in these kinds of problems is that you need an infinite loop somewhere in your program that is broken out of once a condition is satisfied.

Comment: @Tomothy32 ..._or_ you could use `while condition: thing()`. For this example it would be `while usrStr != 'q': #etc..` and removing the `break`. Infinite loops are not _always_ needed, but I tend to use them a lot as well.

Comment: @EthanK The problem with your solution is that it will still attempt to split and print the string.

Comment: @Tomothy32 No, it will work the same, but a before the while loop a line like: `usrStr = 'anythingButQ'` will have to be added, which is why I am pointing out that the `break` solution works better here, but **has the same effect**.

Comment: @EthanK Have you tried it yet? `while` loop conditions are evaluated only after every iteration, meaning that the code within the `while` loop will still be executed once before the loop condition evaluates and breaks out of the loop. i.e. https://pastebin.com/4DsPSnKd

Comment: @Tomothy32. Yes... but that can be fixed by moving the `usrStr = input()` call to the end of the while loop and doing some conditional checks at the beginning. I agree that _for this case_ `break` is better, but I was just pointing out the infinite loops are not always needed. You are right, though. I didn’t have a chance to test it and made the mistake while sight reading and coding in my head. Sorry.